# c++ - calling function by address fails

Tags: c++, memory-address

I was reading up on various things on CodeProject and I found this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29527/Reverse-Engineering-and-Function-Calling-by-Addres

So what I did was I created an injector and a DLL, and grabbed the sample executable file. It basically outputs this when you press F11:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIygV.jpg

So I followed the entire tutorial, but the thing is that the address used in the DLL is always changing. This one to be specific:

```
pFunctionAddress pMySecretFunction = (pFunctionAddress)(0x004113C0);
```

In his tutorial the address for the function is 0x004113C0. In mine it is something else, and I take the one I have and use it. It works perfectly, but when I close the executable and open it, it won't work anymore, and OllyDbg shows that the address is a totally new one.

So I researched a bit and I started adding breakpoints with OllyDbg. I found out that the address is always going to be:

```
main + 4C
```

Where I guess "main" is the main module of these executable. How can I find this address to the function always? Because it changes all the time and I am clueless at this point. In this article I read it doesn't go through what happens when the executable is re-opened, and I've spent 5 hours trying to find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Huge thanks to everyone. Thanks to mfc especially, I have **finally** figured it out! What I ended up doing was whenever I hit DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, I set a global HMODULE to the address of the executable, like this:

```
HMODULE g_hExeModule;
g_hExeModule = GetModuleHandle(L"TutExample.exe");
```

And after a few tests it seems like the function address is always the address of the executable + 0x11014, so in the call I just do:

```
pFunctionAddress pMySecretFunction = (pFunctionAddress)((DWORD)g_hExeModule + 0x11014);
```

Comment: Since you found it once, why can't you find it again the same way?

Comment: Well, `void (*fPtr)() = (void (*)())((char *)&main + 0x4C);`

Comment: I am running Windows 7 64-bit right now. And David Schwartz - I am trying to call this function from the DLL I have injected, so the address has to be hardcoded into my DLL, or a method to find the dynamic address.

And H2CO3: "main" is not a variable, so I can't really use it in my program. It is just what OllyDbg shows me ("jumped from main+4C") and this never changes so if I find a way to get the address of "main" I can add a 4C offset and the function will always be there, I think.

Comment: Try &main like h2co3 says...

Comment: @user1968392 `main()` is a function. It has an address. What I wrote is valid C and C++ code.

Comment: @H2CO3 The thing is, I can't call it because it doesn't exist for me (perhaps because I am doing this in a DLL). This is exactly what I am trying to achieve: the real test program outputs something when you press F11, and that is by calling a function called mySecretFunction(). I am injecting a DLL that waits for F2 to be pressed, and call that function with our own parameters. This function address is always changing and I can't call it after the executable is re-opened. My "way" of calling it is:

 pFunctionAddress pMySecretFunction = (pFunctionAddress)(I_need_main_address_of_proc + 0x4C);

Comment: @user1968392 Perhaps `pFunc = (char *)dlsym(NULL, "main") + 0x4C;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot edit my post nor add any remark, so I have to post this as a new answer.

Your result:

```
Exe loaded at: 00000000 (wrong, probably: 00BE0000 and offset is: 00001005)
Target function at: 00BE1005
Exe loaded at: 00000000 (wrong, probably: 01230000 and offset is: 00001005)
Target function at: 01231005
Exe loaded at: 00000000 (wrong, probably: 012A0000 and offset is: 00001005)
Target function at: 012A1005
```

Please check the name of your compiled exe, is it "TutExample.exe" ? if not, change it to the exact name in the call to GetModuleHandle.

The value of "00000000" indicates that the GetModuleHandle fails because the name "TutExample.exe" is not found in the current memory space.

The address of target function seems ok. Just minus this address with the address of loaded exe and you will get the offset inside the exe memory layout.

You can do this same math inside your injected dll to alway tracks the target function address correctly no matter how the os loads the exe.

Comment: `Exe loaded at: 00270000
Target function at: 00281014`

`Exe loaded at: 00A20000
Target function at: 00A31014`

`Exe loaded at: 01260000
Target function at: 01271014`

Here are three executions with right loaded addresses. I am clueless to how to get these values from my injected DLL (address of the target function -- this is my problem, so we're back to square 1)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have successfully added this to my DLL and it works perfect:

`HMODULE g_hExeModule;
g_hExeModule = GetModuleHandle(L"TutExample.exe");`

And in the thread I just do `pFunctionAddress pMySecretFunction = (pFunctionAddress)((DWORD)g_hExeModule + 0x11014);`

Answer (score 1):

> so if I find a way to get the address of "main" I can add a 4C offset and the function will always be there, I think

Again, functions **do have an address:**

```
void *(funcPtr)() = (void (*)())((char *)&main +  0x4C);

// If you were right, and you also substituted the appropriate
// function signature above, then this should work:

funcPtr();
```

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart LOL, you just made my day, Sir.

Comment: First time I post a question here and I see now that I may have caused confusion.

I do not have a function called "main". OllyDbg refers to the entry point of the process as "main". I am injecting a DLL and I want it to be able to call the function "mySecretFunction" through its address, but it is always changing when the executable is re-opened. Please let me know if I am not making sense.

Comment: @user1968392 If you're really writing this program in C++, then you **must** have a function named `main()`. At most you can't access it from within a DLL, in which case you can still use `dlsym()` ()or `GetProcAddress()` or what the heck it's called on Windows).

Comment: @user1968392 So how about `void *pMain = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "main"); pFunc = (char *)pMain + 0x4c;`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Now I changed my code to this: http://pastebin.com/ADmWNCZc

It crashes when I press F2 after I inject the DLL, so I am certain that didn't work. Sorry if I am being a pain!

Answer (score 1):

The function that you are trying to call is inside of the exe file, so the reference offset should be relative to the memory address that the exe is loaded.
The offset to the target function should be a constant, changed only after each compilation of the source code.

To find out more about your exe, add these two line into your exe:

```
printf(_T("Exe loaded at: %08X"), GetModuleHandle(_T("TutExample.exe")));
printf(_T("Target function at: %08X"), mySecretFunction);
```

Comment: Here are three executions (I compiled the .exe and ran it, this is not debugging inside Visual Studio!):

`Exe loaded at: 00000000
Target function at: 00BE1005`

----------------------------

`Exe loaded at: 00000000
Target function at: 01231005`

----------------------------

`Exe loaded at: 00000000
Target function at: 012A1005`

Answer (score 0):

Newer OS's have a feature called ASLR (Address space layout randomization).  Criminals use some of the trick you are using.  So to make bad guys lives more difficult, EXE and DLL's get assigned a different address every time you run a program.

If you compiled the DLL, there is an option to disable ASLR for your DLL.

Comment: It's not the DLL that causes the issues -- it is the address of the function that gets randomized. ASLR is irrelevant to this.

Comment: Under Windows your EXE file is treated similar to a DLL and ASLR will randomize where your EXE is placed also.

Comment: ASLR happens only once per reboot.